# Resources$NotFoundException on Samsung

Tags: android, drawable, samsung-mobile

One of my app is crashing on Samsung S5 (SM G900V to be precise) with this exception:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_focus_light.9.png from drawable resource ID #0x7f0200e5
   at android.content.res.Resources$CRunnable_openmp.doOpenMP(Resources.java:1097)
   at android.content.res.Resources$__ompClass0.__doWork(Resources.java:1029)
   at com.samsung.javaomp.runtime.__OMPThread.run()
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_focus_light.9.png
   at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetNative(AssetManager.java)
   at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAsset(AssetManager.java:408)
   at android.content.res.Resources$CRunnable_openmp.doOpenMP(Resources.java:1092)
   at android.content.res.Resources$__ompClass0.__doWork(Resources.java:1029)
   at com.samsung.javaomp.runtime.__OMPThread.run()
```

Seems like app is unable to access some drawable from android OS. Any ideas how to solve it?

**UPDATE:** May be this part is causing it but again its just a guess:

```
Integer resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SERVICE_MISSING ||
        resultCode == ConnectionResult.SERVICE_DISABLED ||
        resultCode == ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED) {
    Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, 0);
    if (dialog != null) {
        //This dialog will help the user update to the latest GooglePlayServices
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** Unzipping apk file reveals this file `res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_focus_light.9.png`

[image]

Comment: Do you have a common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_focus_light.9.png file in the res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4 directory?

Comment: I don't have a `drawable-xxhdpi-v4` directory in first place. Searching for `common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_focus_light.9.png` on Google makes me feel that this is some internal resource accessed by Google play services.

Comment: do You have Admob inside Your app and obfuscated with ProGuard?

Comment: Yea, seems like the app is using a really old support library and that the Google play services has deprecated it for higher resolutions. You cannot upgrade from android.support.v4.app?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs Nope, I don't have any ad related thing inside app.

Comment: ok, but You are using play services? because this missed png is part of the google play services sdk

Comment: @Opiatefuchs The only place where I am accessing Google Play Services is those lines I just edited in question.

Comment: so You must have integrated google play service sdk, or? it doesn´t matter where You using it. I saw on my samsung galaxy s3 some different behaviour, similar to Yours. If am wright and You have integrated gps sdk, can You open this bug related folder and look if this pic is inside? It must be anywhere under libs....

Comment: @Opiatefuchs I have just uncompressed final apk file and there is indeed a file `res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_focus_light.9.png`

Comment: The question is whether the index in the `R.java` corresponds to it properly, the resource ID i mean.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce If something was wrong with `R.java` then app should crash on every device whereas app crashes only on Samsung devices, most prominently on SM G900V.

Comment: not necessarily...this relates to how samsung has done their android port...example: I had two string folders, one german, one default. I put some strings inside default string.file but forget it to put it into german one. While other devices put the String from the default string resources, samsung s3 failed to get this....

Comment: I think a try could be to remove the google play service sdk, attach it again and clean the project....

Comment: But I can't just reproduce it, I am receiving these crash reports whereas app works fine for me on same device.

Comment: Same is happening for me, I opened here http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=General&messageId=284984&listLines=15&startId=zzzzz~ and here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=186013

Comment: I'm facing this issue 2 years later in 2017. Samsung is such a piece of shit! I Had to say it.

Comment: Issue still exists

Answer (score 4):

It may be related to a bug in Android Gradle plugin <= 1.1.0:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79325

Meanwhile, you can flip shrinkResources to false and the problem will be solved.

Comment: Problem still exists in latest 1.2.+ and its only affecting Samsung devices.

Comment: Can someone confirm that setting shrinkResources to false will solve the problem?

Comment: I´m using 1.3.1 and still happens

Comment: Using gradle:2.3.0-beta2 and still happens, samsung is the worst

Answer (score 0):

As pvin...@gmail said here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=186013 try disabling shringResources in the gradle file:

`shrinkResources false`