# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable compat_splash_screen_no_icon_background with resource ID #0x7f0801b6

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-splashscreen

I am getting this issue only for samsung galaxy devices- Galaxy Tab A, Galaxy A03 Core, Galaxy A02, Galaxy A32

Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp.application/com.myapp.application.ui.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.app.application:drawable/compat_splash_screen_no_icon_background with resource ID #0x7f0801b6

My configuration->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <style name="Theme.App.Starting" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
        <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/white</item>

        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/splash_icon</item>

        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.Triva.NoActionBar</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenIconBackgroundColor">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration">800</item>

        <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

This is the resource in read only file ->

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is currently an issue. You will have to wait a bit for the fix to ship, then update the `core-splashscreen` dependency to the latest version.

It is tracked here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/229645249
See if the call order they suggest there helps you mitigate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and noticed the bug was only happening on low display density devices (lower than hdpi, i.e. `tvdpi`, `mdpi` and `ldpi`). So I managed to reproduce the crash by setting up a `tvdpi` emulator, and I also confirmed there was no crash on an `hdpi` emulator.

As a fix, I copied the `drawable` (webp) file from `drawable-xxxhdpi` to `drawable-mdpi` and scaled it down by a factor of 4 (512px to 128px) because `xxxhdpi` is 4x`mdpi`. See [official docs](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities).

Note: If you want to also support `ldpi`, you need to add a drawable in `drawable-ldpi` because it won't read it from any other drawable folder. You can scale down from 512px to 96px, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename the resource file.
Looks like it interferes with some of Samsung's resource files and you have such runtime error.

Comment: That resource is read only @daniil krant

Answer (score 0):

The background must be a color value, drawables are not supported (at least for now). You can review the example in docs (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen)

working example:

```
<item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
```

Comment: Yes I did used a color value - <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/white</item>

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to [Resources$NotFoundException on Samsung](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28983622/resourcesnotfoundexception-on-samsung)

You can try disabling `isShrinkResources` on release builds.

Eg. In your project `build.gradle.kts` file

```
    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isShrinkResources = false
        }
    }
```